# tf.one_hot returns <tf.Tensor 'one_hot:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification, categorization

As the shape is None I'm not able to process further. I need full shape after one_hot encoding.

```
labels = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels,5)
```

Which Returns

```
<tf.Tensor 'one_hot:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>)
```

This results in value error

```
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: 
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(5)])
```

Comment: What line is giving you the ValueError?

Comment: tf.train.batch()

Comment: why it is returning shape(?,5)

Comment: <tf.Tensor 'one_hot:0' shape=(8, 5) dtype=float32>

Comment: How come? I want like this <tf.Tensor 'one_hot:0' shape=(8, 5) dtype=float32> only can you share the answer